# How to set time duration using AVAudioRecorder exactly for 3 minutes in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I am working with AVAudioRecorder for setting recording time duration from 3 minutes but it's not estimate proper time interval. It's recording up to 3 min 7 sec but I need to stop recording at 3 min.

I am using this code:

```
let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(value: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: NSNumber(value:1),
    AVSampleRateKey: NSNumber(value:8000.0)
]

do {
    recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
    recorder.delegate = self
    recorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    recorder.record(forDuration: 180.00) // record for 3 minutes
```

Comment: Use timer function